# Creating and Setting title of UIButton in FOR loop breaks loop

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my app I'm creating a paged slider (UISlider + UIPageControl). The app reaches out to CoreData to get the array of Entities to create a "page" for.

I build the paginated scroller n the following loop:

```
for i in 0..<features.count {
        var pageWidth = Int(view.frame.width)*i
        var pageView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(pageWidth), 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height))
        pageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        pageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //Background image
        var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.width, scrollView.frame.height))
        var image:UIImage!
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        pageView.addSubview(imageView)

        if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(features[i].coverImage){
            //The background image
            image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.features[i].coverImage)
            imageView.image = image
        }
        else if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(features[i].coverImage) && !features[i].coverImage.isEmpty {
            FileStoreClient.downloadFileIfNotExists(features[i].cover, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.features[i].coverImage)
                    imageView.image = image
                }
                else {
                    println("There was an error during the download")
                }
            })
        }

        //The background cover
        var coverView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, 250))
        coverView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
        pageView.addSubview(coverView)

        //The title
        var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 40, view.frame.width-20, 25))
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Haymaker", size: 24)
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        titleLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        titleLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
        titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        titleLabel.text = features[i].title
        pageView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        //The text
        var textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, titleLabel.frame.origin.y+titleLabel.frame.height+5, view.frame.width-20, 60))
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 13)
        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        textLabel.text = features[i].summary
        pageView.addSubview(textLabel)

        //The button
        var readMoreButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, pageView.frame.height - 90, 200, 80))
        readMoreButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: Strings.readMoreButtonTitle, attributes: Fonts.featureButtonText), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //readMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: "readArticle", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        readMoreButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        readMoreButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        readMoreButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        readMoreButton.center.x = pageView.center.x
        pageView.addSubview(readMoreButton)

        println(i)

        scrollView.addSubview(pageView)
}
```

Everything works exactly as it should, except that the moment I try to assign a title to the new button, the loop turns into an infinite loop. If I print out the current index of the loop, it keeps cycling through endlessly. Example:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

If I comment out the `myButton.setTitle()` method, the problem goes away and the indexes print out like the following:

```
0
1
2
```

I have tried setTitle and setAttributedTitle, both of which have the same effect. I have tried dispatching different queues and nothing seems to be working.

Again, everything works for the background image, the two labels, views, etc. Problem only exists when a button is brought into the mix. The issue exists even if I remove the `FileStoreManager` code.

Something about a button in a for loop isn't happy.

---

***EDIT #1***

I decided to try and create a new project just to test button creation in a for loop. This works perfectly fine.

```
var x = 20
var y = 20

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 1...10 {
        var myview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y), 100, 50))
        var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50))
        button.setTitle("Test", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2
        myview.addSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(myview)
        x = x+20
        y = y+20
        println(i)
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try fast enumeration in case something is somehow getting messed up in your range.

```
for feature in features { ... }
```

or if you need the index:

```
for (index, features) in features.enumerate() { ... }
```

Not sure it will resolve the issue, but it might increase readability.

Comment: Thanks for the readability suggestion. I figured out the problem, but also implemented your suggestion in order to keep it legible.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because I had the above code in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() function. Something about setting a buttons title triggers the method, it seems.

As I needed to use this method due to dynamic sizes, I simply added a "hasLoaded:Bool" to check if the function has already fired.

This resolved the issue.